# How to get MOL object from ConvMol object of deepchem

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning

About python library deepchem, how to get the mol object or smiles from ConvMol object of deepchem.

example

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import deepchem as dc
from deepchem.models.tensorgraph.models.graph_models import GraphConvModel

tox21_tasks, tox21_datasets, transformers = dc.molnet.load_tox21(featurizer='GraphConv')
train_dataset, valid_dataset, test_dataset = tox21_datasets

print(train_dataset.X)
>>> <deepchem.feat.mol_graphs.ConvMol object at 0x7...>
```

I want to get MOL object of or SMILES of each data.

Answer (score 0):

The `ConvMol`object is a custom featurization used by DeepChem's graph convolutions, so it's not possible to get the SMILES strings from them. However, from your example, you have `train_dataset`, a deepchem `Dataset` object. You can recover the set of SMILES as `train_dataset.ids`. These will be in the same order as the `ConvMol` objects in `train_dataset.X`.